# Installing Flask-WTF with Anaconda: ImportError: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal'

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, conda, werkzeug

I'm super confused right now. I had a working Python code using Flask. Then I wanted to install Flask-WTF to improve on possible CSRF and since its not working anymore. I'm working with conda to manage my environments.

To start with I prompted `conda install Flask-WTF`. Since then I get the error: `ImportError: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal'`  from the line I import flask, when executing my python script. It was some time in between, so I'm not 100% sure if indeed this is the reason.

Unfortunately I don't know which version of flask I had installed before, but when checking with `conda list --revisions` the previous revision apparently had flask-2.2.2 and werkzeug-2.2.2 installed. Then the revision I initiated updated the following:

```
     ca-certificates  {2023.01.10 (anaconda/win-64) -> 2023.08.22 (defaults/win-64)}
     certifi  {2022.12.7 (anaconda/win-64) -> 2023.7.22 (defaults/win-64)}
     flask  {2.2.2 (anaconda/win-64) -> 2.2.2 (defaults/win-64)}
     itsdangerous  {2.0.1 (anaconda/noarch) -> 2.0.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     openssl  {3.0.10 (defaults/win-64) -> 3.0.11 (defaults/win-64)}
     werkzeug  {2.2.2 (anaconda/win-64) -> 2.2.3 (defaults/win-64)}
    +dnspython-2.2.1 (defaults/win-64)
    +email-validator-1.2.1 (defaults/win-64)
    +flask-wtf-1.0.1 (defaults/win-64)
    +wtforms-2.3.3 (defaults/noarch)
```

What I don't understand though: When I run `conda list` werkzeug is listed as version 2.3.7

I thought, no problem, just go back to the stage before that with `conda install --revision N` (N the number of revision before installing Flask-WTF), but then I got the error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - anaconda/win-64::ca-certificates==2023.01.10=haa95532_0
  - anaconda/noarch::itsdangerous==2.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::click==8.1.7=win_pyh7428d3b_0
  - anaconda/win-64::flask==2.2.2=py39haa95532_0
  - anaconda/win-64::werkzeug==2.2.2=py39haa95532_0
  - anaconda/win-64::certifi==2022.12.7=py39haa95532_0
```

I also saw some previous post with the error message that said updating werkzeug solved it, but not for me. I ran `conda update werkzeug`, but also I felt like I did not do anything, so maybe its more of a problem with conda. My conda version is 23.3.1, Python version is 3.9.18.

Therefore any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I solved my problem by explicitly saying `conda install werkzeug==2.2.2`, but still curious why it didn't work with my method before and also why the newest version of werkzeug doesn't work

Comment: I'd guess this is a side-effect of *ad hoc* channel specifications. That is, you probably don't have `anaconda` and `conda-forge` specified in your configuration, so Conda is only searching `defaults` and concludes it can't find any package like `anaconda/win-64::foo` or `conda-forge/noarch::bar`. Generally, Conda gives a far better experience if you manage your environments through YAML files that explicitly define the channels and their order. Using `conda install -c <channel>` can be counterproductive to reproducibility.

Comment: Alternatively, you might have been able to rollback exactly by adding `-c anaconda` and `-c conda-forge` to the `conda install --revision` command.